# How can I get back my balance showing in my IOTA wallet?

Tags: tangle, wallet, balances

I use IOTA Wallet Version 2.5.7 (2.5.7). I know I had 101.89800000 IOT in my wallet (my cointracking.info account confirms). I was able to log into my account, but my balance is showing 0. I tried steps outlined here: https://forum.helloiota.com/588/Help-My-IOTA-balance-is-zero-steps-to-help-you-find-your-balance-v254?PageIndex=1 several times, and I couldn't get the balance to show up. I then took my address searched here: https://iotasear.ch/ , but it shows a 404 page. The newer addresses I generated as part of the process outlined here: https://forum.helloiota.com/588/Help-My-IOTA-balance-is-zero-steps-to-help-you-find-your-balance-v254?PageIndex=1 – all show up in my search.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get back my IOT?

Guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please try using https://thetangle.org/ instead of https://iotasear.ch/ to check if the balance exists on your address?